# MySQL get Offset given Limit, Order By, and Where ID

Tags: mysql, pagination, limit, offset

I have a table that displays 10 rows per page.  Now, given an item's ID, how can I get the "page" that the item is on?

In other words, I'm looking for the offset (multiple of 10) given an ID of a record.

```
SELECT * FROM items
WHERE category = "category"
LIMIT ?, 10      <----- TRYING TO FIGURE OUT HOW TO GET ? OFFSET GIVEN ID
ORDER BY id DESC
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SET @rownum = 0; 
Select sub.*, 10 * Floor(sub.rownum / 10) as pagenum
from
(
   Select *,  (@rownum:=@rownum+1) as rownum
   from items order by id desc
) sub
where sub.ID = givenID;
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it;

```
SELECT 10*FLOOR(COUNT(id)/10) FROM items where id < YOUR_ID
```

Comment: The order of items returned by `SELECT` is formally unpredictable, so this won't necessarily work.